# Laravel не работает метод store в ресурсном контроллере

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь создать отзыв, прописал ресурсный контроллер:

```
public function create()
{

    return view('comment.create',[
        'comment' => []
    ]);
}


public function store(Request $request)
{

    Comment::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('create');
}
```

dd реагирует, только в create store как-будто не подключается.

Вот скрин роутов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама форма создания:

```
<div class="container">

    <hr/>

    <form id="form-horizontal" class="" action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}


        {{-- form include--}}
        @include('comment.partials.form')
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: А что значит "dd реагирует"? Это же какой-то var_dump laravel'евский? Может он умный и не шлёт данные сразу, и не прерывает редирект.

Comment: да, это var_dump с die одновременно

Comment: В таком случае, что же отвечает `POST /`? Откройте инструменты разработчика (часто f12) и во вкладке Сеть, посмотрите куда уходит запрос и что прилетает в ответ. Попробуйте дёрнуть ручку курлом (типа: `curl -X POST http://localhost/`.)